# Не обновляются приложения в ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, update, terminal

При попытке обновить все через терминал `sudo apt-get update` выдает

```js
Игн:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Сущ:2 http://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-disk/deb stable InRelease                   
Сущ:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Сущ:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Сущ:5 http://deb.playonlinux.com natty InRelease                               
Игн:6 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-gamora-amd InRelease
Сущ:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Сущ:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
.
.
.
Игн:50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Игн:51 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-ru_RU
Игн:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-ru
Игн:53 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ошк:63 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease
  Could not resolve host: download.sublimetext.com
Игн:54 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Игн:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
```

Игнорированно абсолютно все. Все сообщения не стал вставлять - уж слишком много. А в конце пишет вот вот:

```js
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
W: Репозиторий «http://ppa.launchpad.net/olivier-berten/misc/ubuntu xenial Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Данные из этого репозитория нельзя аутентифицировать, и поэтому потенциально из небезопасно использовать.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
W: Репозиторий «http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Данные из этого репозитория нельзя аутентифицировать, и поэтому потенциально из небезопасно использовать.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
W: Репозиторий «http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Данные из этого репозитория нельзя аутентифицировать, и поэтому потенциально из небезопасно использовать.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
```

Ну и в таком стиле. При обновлении через менеджер обновлений пишет, мол нужно обновить приложения из недостоверных источников, и все: либо "Ок", либо "Настройки".
Подскажите пожалуйста что с этим делать? И почему вообще все так?

Comment: начните с удаления записей, перечисленных в последнем списке. они находятся в файлах в каталоге `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin у меня только sources.list

Comment: не страшно. удаляйте из этого файла

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Прошу прощения, был невнимателен. Есть такая папка и после Вашего совета  все обновилось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @alexanderbarakin начните с удаления записей, перечисленных в последнем списке. они находятся в файлах в каталоге `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Все обновилось